# Remove [] square brackets from DocBlockr comment

Tags: sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin, docblocks

I like the plugin [DocBlockr](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/DocBlockr) for sublime text but I would like my comments to be a bit different.

The normal appearence:
[image]

And how I would like them to appear:

[image]

So the `type`, `description` without the `[]` square brackets is there anyway of doing this? I've googled and looked trought the documentation but couldn't find it. The lower images is directly taken from the documentation page.

I hope someone could help me with this as making comments would become a lot easier.

Comment: I've been wanting to remove them myself in Atom (note, not Sublime), and just realised they actually serve a purpose . On creation of the block, the description brackets are highlighted, and using the tab keys you can navigate between the `[]` items. Thought I'd share incase it helps anyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to do this, but you will have to do it individually for each language. I'll show you how to do it for PHP as an example. In order to do this, I'm going to assume you have `PackageResourceViewer` installed (you can install it through Package Control). Follow these steps:

1. Open up command palette (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>)
2. Type `PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Type `DocBlockr` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. Using the arrow keys, find the file named `php.sublime-completions`, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Doing this should open up the completions for your PHP files. You can make whatever modifications you want for your DocBlockr completions for the specific language.

Comment: I am using DocBlockr with Atom on Mac, I could not find any file with extension .subline-completions in DocBlockr package folder. Any suggestion?